# How to reinstall magento 2, including the plugins and the theme?

Tags: magento2, database, upgrade, magento-upgrade

I have 43 extensions installed and a paid theme. The extensions' seller installed the extensions and configured them.

I want to update Magento to 2.3.2 from 2.3.1, I have a complete server backup in case things went wrong, an AWS snapshot.

I have to move to another server too, so I have to do a fresh installation of Magento 2.3.2, once that's done, is there any way to import everything without reinstalling one by one?

Is there any way to import the database and plugins and themes from there to the other server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply take the file backup and database backup from old server and put all the file on new server and import the database on new server then you just have to change the database credentials in "app/etv/env.php" file and base URL from table "core_config_data" after doing all this now your setup is working fine now you can upgrade Magento version you can follow the steps given in here : 
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html

Comment: what about the extensions and the theme? should I reinstall them one by one? Or is there some folder I can copy?

Comment: you can copy the whole Magento installation you need not reinstall anything